# Find a formula for forecasting of the sum of $n$ iid processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, self-learning, conditional-expectation

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb N}$ be a infinite time series. We know that the forecasting or prediction of $X_{T+h}$ if we observe $X_1,...,X_T$ is
$$P_{X_1,..,X_T}(X_{T+h})= E[X_{T+h} | X_1,..., X_T ]$$
Now, suppose $X^j=(X_t^j)_{t\in \mathbb N}$, $j=1,...,n$ *iid* coppies of $X$. Define:
$$Y_t = X_t^1 + ...+ X_t^n$$
Suppose that we only observe $Y_1,.., Y_T$. We know that:
$$P_{Y_1,..,Y_T}(Y_{T+h})=E[Y_{T+h}|Y_1,...,Y_T]=\sum_{j=1}^n E[X^j_{T+h}| Y_1,...,T_T ]$$
But I want to know if there is any formula for $P_{Y_1,..,Y_T}(Y_{T+h})$ involving $P_{X_1,..,X_T}(X_{T+h})$. I think I can do this:
$$P_{Y_1,..,Y_T}(Y_{T+h})=\sum_{j=1}^n E[X^j_{T+h}| Y_1,...,T_T ]=nE[X_{T+h}| Y_1,...,T_T ]= n P_{Y_1,..,Y_T}(X_{T+h})$$
But I don't know if this equal to $nP_{X_1,..,X_T}(X_{T+h})$.